# Identify width of div from previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website with a set layout, yet one element expands to a certain width for that specific page through `.animate()`.

This works statically, so if I know from which page I came. Yet, if the order changes then the width of the elements do not correspond any more.

**What I need is a way to identify what page I came from then set the width of the div on the current page to the width of the div on the previous page. Then change the width to what is needed in order to create a smooth transition.**

This is all within the same website, yet different html documents per page.

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var WidthDivPrev    =   get width div page from user came
    $("#currentdiv").css({
            "width": "WidthDivPrev", 
    });

    $( "#currentdiv" ).animate({
           width:"800px",
    }, 1500 );  
});
```

This piece of code is what I can't figure out

> **var  WidthDivPrev    =   [get width div page from user came]**

or maybe even

> **var  IDpage  =   [pagefrom which user came]**

even if you can do the last then I can use an if function to get the width from the CSS

Comment: You have to store the width somewhere, like session.

Comment: Is your current page is new window? or just page change (like form change) same window?

Comment: It is just a page change

Comment: like a wizard am i right?

Comment: Euhm, I am new with jquery so if I understand a wizard correctly then no.  it works through an html link; landingpage.html has a link to secondpage.html and I need to get the width from the div on landingpage.html for example

Comment: can't you pass width through querystring like `yourpage.php?divWidth=300` and then on page use `$_GET['divWidth']` to grab div width

Comment: +1 for your idea.. It shows continuity...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the width of current page in the *[`sessionStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute)*

```
if (sessionStorage.divWidth)
{
    //page came from some page of your site
    $("#currentdiv").css({
        "width": sessionStorage.divWidth+"px" //set the current divWidth equal to previous pages divWidth
    });

    $("#currentdiv").animate({
        "width": "800px"
    }, 1500);  
}
else
{
    sessionStorage.divWidth = "800"; // set the session variable for the next page
}
```

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Thanks, it took some time to figure out how to apply it and check if it worked everywhere but it works like a charm!!!

Comment: @Wiebe You might need to use http://modernizr.com/ to make it work in older versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

**Session Storage is also a better way but here is one another approach**

Make a variable in your master page for setting width of selected div and then set value of it when your required page loads take variable value for setting width of div.

**Code in // Master or Common Page**

```
var widthOfDiv = '';
```

**Set Value of it in first page**

> widthOfDiv =  $("#currentdiv").width();

**access this value in second page**

```
$("#newdiv").width(widthOfDiv);
```